# Do not allow to open UIPickerview in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, xcode8

Let me know if value is not available in UiPickerView, then do not allow to open UiPickerView?

How to handle this situation in objective C.

Thanks you,
Shriram.

Comment: From where you are getting UIPickerView values

Comment: from JSON array

Comment: Generally, you will show data in `UIPickerView` from array, check the count of array, if its greater then zero show the `UIPickerView` else don't show it.

Comment: how can I check or how can I wire in code?
I am writing below code


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.values count];
   
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if

```
[self.values count]>0
```

then write

```
yourPickerView.delegate=self;
yourPickerView.datasource=self;
```

If you don't call delegate and datasource then this method won't be called

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component { return [self.values count]; }
```

Comment: Hi Zaheer,



Can you please explain below code, how can I use your code?






[self.values count]>0




then write




yourPickerView.delegate=self;



yourPickerView.datasource=self;



where I use this code?

Comment: where you are storing your data in self.values array/dictionary? If it is the response of some web service call then call yourPickerView.delegate=self; yourPickerView.datasource=self; on the response of service call and if you have saved [self.values] locally then replace it in your ViewDidLoad/ViewDidAppear.